# Problem in for loop pass of selection sort

Tags: python, sorting, for-loop, selection-sort

I am trying to implement selection sort my own way. I am getting the 'sorted_list' in a sorted fashion. However, I am unable to figure out as to why after finding out that Zurich is the highest element, the next for loop pass skips capetown. This is true for all instances where I find the next highest element.In all these instances the next step in the for loop skips the element next to the highest element.

```py
names=['Newyork', 'London', 'Tokyo','Manila','New-Delhi',
       'Osaka','Munich','Berlin','Newcastle', 'Turin','Moscow','Sydney',
       'Zurich','Capetown']
sorted_list=[]

while names:

    for name in names:
     print(name)
     element_index = names.index(name)
     index=0
     while index<len(names):

      if name > names[index] or name == names[index]:
         print(index)
         index += 1

         if index == len(names):
             names.pop(element_index)
             sorted_list.append(name)

             break
      if name < names[index]:
       break
```

output:

```
Newyork
0
1
London
Tokyo
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
Manila
New-Delhi
Osaka
0
1
Munich
Berlin
Newcastle
Turin
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
Moscow
Sydney
0
1
Zurich
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
Newyork
0
1
London
Tokyo
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
Manila
New-Delhi
Osaka
0
1
Munich
Berlin
Newcastle
Turin
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
Sydney
0
1
Capetown
Newyork
0
1
London
Tokyo
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
New-Delhi
Osaka
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
Munich
Berlin
Newcastle
Moscow
Sydney
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
Newyork
0
1
2
3
London
Manila
New-Delhi
Osaka
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
Berlin
Newcastle
Moscow
Capetown
Newyork
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
Manila
0
1
New-Delhi
0
1
2
3
4
Munich
0
1
Berlin
Newcastle
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
Capetown
London
0
Manila
0
1
New-Delhi
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
Berlin
Moscow
0
1
Capetown
London
0
Manila
0
1
Munich
0
1
2
3
4
5
Moscow
0
1
2
3
4
London
0
Manila
0
1
2
3
Capetown
London
0
1
2
Capetown
0
1
Berlin
0
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this snippet should explain what happens.

```
>>> L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> for i, elem in enumerate(L):
...     L.pop(i)
...
1
3
5
```

when you `.pop()` `"Zurich"` from `names` `"Capetown"` will be shifted to the place of `"Zurich"` and you for loop try to go to the next element AFTER this `"Capetown"`.

It is not safe to modify `list` when you iterate through it.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @V.Ayrat Try this it might solve your purpose

```
 names=['Newyork', 'London', 'Tokyo','Manila','New-Delhi', 'Osaka','Munich','Berlin','Newcastle', 
               'Turin','Moscow','Sydney', 'Zurich','Capetown'] 
        # sorted_list=[]
        for i in range(len(names)): 
            min_idx = i 
            for j in range(i+1, len(names)): 
                if names[min_idx] > names[j]: 
                    min_idx = j 

            names[i], names[min_idx] = names[min_idx], names[i]
```